# How to divide contacted cicles in images by using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have several images to process. I want to  divide all the circles in the image.Here is it. 
[A image from CT scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic6QM.png)

And here is my code.

import cv2
import numpy as np

```
def detect_circle(image):
    dst = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (3,3), 0)#降低噪声
    climage = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(climage, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 50, param1 = 35, param2 = 27,
                              minRadius = 25, maxRadius = 50)
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0, 1:]:
    cv2.circle(image, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 0, 255), 2)#画圆
    cv2.circle(image, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 1)#画圆心
    #cv2.imwrite('detect_circle-1.tif', image)

cv2.namedWindow('detect_circle', 0)
cv2.resizeWindow('detect_circle', 800, 800)
cv2.imshow('detect_circle', image)  

img = cv2.imread('C:\THU\python\learn\outputtif\\1.tif')
detect_circle(img)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Then,I got a image like this. The result is perfect enough.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xMIX.png)

And I also tried to use erode and dilate to divided them into single.But it doesnt work.My question is how to divide these contacted circles into single,so I can detect them.

Comment: Can you indent your code properly? You just have to put 4 spaces in front of your code so that it comes in a neat code-block. Or, you can select all your code and press `ctrl + k` which automatically indents the code for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a newcomers, I will modify this question.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) using watershed might help.

Comment: Can you show expected result?

Comment: @Alderven, I want to divide this circles and extract cement matrix between this circles.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVFPi.png)

Comment: @J.D. I have tried Watershed Algorithm, however, result is not accurate. I cannot extract matrix between circles.